# How to make function end no sooner than specified time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to finish some query no sooner than 500ms.

I don't want to waste that 500ms either, like delaying everything like here:

```
someFunction(someService) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    getDataFromBackend().then(data => {
      someService.makeAnAction();
    });
  }, 500);
}
```

How to start getting the data from the backend at once but do something with that data not too soon?

Comment: Store the return value of `getDataFromBackend()` in a variable outside of the timeout, then put the `.then` call inside the timeout.

Comment: What is wrong with this question?

Comment: @4castle It wasn't so obvious for me, thanks. I would mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Make a function to get a promise that resolves in the requisite time:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(resolve, ms);
});
```

Wait for both it and your operation to complete:

```
someFunction(someService) {
  return Promise.all([getDataFromBackend(), delay(500)]).then(([data]) => {
    someService.makeAnAction();
  });
}
```

Alternative without destructuring, with Bluebird:

```
someFunction(someService) {
  const dataGet = getDataFromBackend();

  return delay(500).return(dataGet).then(data => {
    someService.makeAnAction();
  });
}
```

Potentially misleading equivalent of the above:

```
someFunction(someService) {
  return delay(500)
    .return(getDataFromBackend())
    .then(data => {
      someService.makeAnAction();
    });
}
```

Async/await:

```
async someFunction(someService) {
  const dataGet = getDataFromBackend();
  await delay(500);
  const data = await dataGet;

  someService.makeAnAction();
}
```